# Comparing converted dates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am trying to compare dates. The comparison is working fine with `<` and `>` signs but when i use `=` its returning zero rows. The query is as follows:

```
SET DateFormat DMY 
SELECT * FROM [Users]  
where name like '%' + replace('', '%', '[%]') + '%'
and email like '%' + replace('', '%', '[%]') + '%' 
and last_edited = CAST('18/3/2014' AS DATETIME) 
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Last_edited,101)  desc
```

what is wrong with this query in `"="` case ?`

Comment: what is the datatype of last_edited column?

Comment: what values of TIME does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your where clause to remove the time portion:

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [last_edited]), 0) = CAST('18/3/2014' AS DATETIME)
```

Based on the column name, I am assuming that `[last_edited]` has values like this `2014-03-18 17:50:08.000`, so you need to remove the time if you want to do an exact comparison with `18/3/2014`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SET DateFormat DMY 
SELECT * FROM [Users]  
where name like '%' + replace('', '%', '[%]') + '%'
and email like '%' + replace('', '%', '[%]') + '%' 
and convert(varchar(25),last_edited,  101) = '03/18/2014'
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Last_edited,101)  desc
```